# WCF crash unexpectedly ,method not allowed 

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have WCF webservice that has contract like this

```
[OperationContract]
void UpdateEncounterStatus(int BookingID, string BookingStatus);
```

and in the class

```
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "UpdateEncounterStatus/{BookingID}/{BookingStatus}")]
        public void UpdateEncounterStatus(int BookingID, string BookingStatus)
```

but when call it , I get

Operation 'UpdateEncounterStatus' in contract 'IPMA' has a path variable named 'BookingID' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.

and when change the parameter to string I got

method not allowed 
any idea how to fix that

Comment: How are you making the call? If you're typing that url into a browser you are doing a GET request, and your method is attributed to only match on a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only string types for the parameters that comes in the route of `UriTemplate`. In your example `BookingID` is `integer` and it comes in the route so it won't work. If you move `BookingID` to querystring them things will work.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545988/can-i-pass-non-string-to-wcf-restful-service-using-uritemplate) for more details.