# Parse custom filter string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, query-string

I'm currently building some custom filters for a web api. I thought of a custom query string that looks like in the following example:

`http://localhost/api/users?filter=`

`age(min:18,max:45),explvl(atleast:60),classes(types:[golem,tank,dozer])`

I didn't want to encode Json to Base64 on the clientside and I find this format much easier to read. Currently I get the filter query parameter back as string.
The question I have is how to effectively transform this format to json and backwards if possible.

I'm also open for alternative solutions that achieve the same readability and provide a parser implementation.

Comment: AFAIK `JSON` wont work as query string because of the `quotation marks`

Comment: There's a few types of invalid characters in there, how is this going to work without any form of encoding? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: why not just use "post" with normal filter object? (json as is)

Comment: @Aleksey: Because I have a `Pagination` mechanism that generates links for the previous and the next page. So I need to pass those filters with some sort of query string. I'm also no fan of using `HTTP POST` in cases I want to `GET` Data.

Comment: @JayMee: I tested the query string and I get it back without problems.

Comment: `GET` will always be kinda limited.. With `POST` you could put filter, pagination and any other stuff inside single "request" entity

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent and you will be fine.

Comment: @Adrian: This would result in a string that is not human readable anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can WCF JSON WebService operation with non-string parameters be called from browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526535/can-wcf-json-webservice-operation-with-non-string-parameters-be-called-from-brow)